# Get the keyword positions for all matched docs with just ONE search query

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm been wrestling with this problem for days.

For example, if I have

```
{doc_id1:"thor marvel"},
{doc_id2:"spiderman thor"}, 
{doc_id3:"the avengers captain america ironman thor"}
```

three documents in elastic search, and do a search query for "thor", I want it to tell me **where keyword "thor" is found in each document**, like

```
{ doc_id1: 1, doc_id2: 2, doc_id3: 6}
```

as the desired result.

I have two possible solution on top of my head now:

1.figure out a way to **put the _vectorterm** info (which includes all the positions/offsets for each token/word of the document) **into _source**, so that I can directly access _vectorterm info in my normal search result. I can then construct the (doc, position) list outside elasticsearch. Normally, you can only access _vectorterm info for a single document at a time given the index/type/id, which is why it's tricky. That should be the ideal way to achieve the goal

2.figure out a way to **trigger an action whenever a new document is added**. This action will scan through all the tokens/words in the new document, create a new "token" index(if it doesn't exist) and append (doc_id, position) pair to it like 
{ keyword:"thor" [ doc_id1:1,doc_id2:2,doc_id3:6] }.
So that I just need to search for "thor" among keywords indexes and then get the (doc, position) lists. This seems to be even harder and less optimal.

Sadly, I don't know how to do either one. I'll appreciate it if someone can give me some help on this. Many thanks!